# How to test a jsforce Node app that requires a security token?

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js, jsforce, continuous-integration, ci

Our Node app that uses [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) bulk upload APIs has a configuration file including this information:

```
    "salesforce" : {
        "username": "...@example.com",
        "password": "...",
        "securityToken": "...",
        "endpoint": "https://...my.salesforce.com"
    }
```

and not surprisingly a Continuous Integration (CI) pipeline is proving hard to create because:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant ...
sfdx force:user:password:generate ...
sfdx force:org:display --json --verbose
```

returns these values:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "devHubId": "...",
    "accessToken": "...",
    "instanceUrl": "...",
    "username": "...",
    "clientId": "...",
    "password": "...",
    "status": "...",
    "expirationDate": "...",
    "createdBy": "...",
    "edition": "...",
    "orgName": "...",
    "createdDate": "..",
    "alias": "..."
  }
```

but it seems [deliberately](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_view_info.htm) not the security token value.

Any suggestions for how to test such an app from a CI pipeline?

Comment: Thanks @identigral, for now I'd rather stick to the current flow but that option is there I guess if I get stuck. I'm going to take a look at this [whitelisting option](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XeU2QAK) next.

Comment: Ah, yes, whitelisting IPs will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [white-listing all possible login addresses](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XeU2QAK) in this addition to `Admin.profile-meta.xml` (that my tests are running under) is the way to go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Profile xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <loginIpRanges>
        <description>For tests only: no security token needed</description>
        <endAddress>255.255.255.255</endAddress>
        <startAddress>0.0.0.0</startAddress>
    </loginIpRanges>
</Profile>
```

with my automation deploying this addition using:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app
```

and then just the username and password will suffice.

Also see the related [How to add an org instanceUrl, username and password to a config file from a Bitbucket pipeline?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383607/how-to-add-an-org-instanceurl-username-and-password-to-a-config-file-from-a-bit).