# How to add an org instanceUrl, username and password to a config file from a Bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: salesforcedx, jsforce, continuous-integration, bitbucket

This relates to [How to test a jsforce Node app that requires a security token?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383544/how-to-test-a-jsforce-node-app-that-requires-a-security-token) As it took me several yours to get this to work, I'm sharing the results to save anyone else needing to do this some of those hours.

The scenario is that I want to test a Node app that uses jsforce in a Continuous Integration (CI) environment, specifically via a Bitbucket pipeline. That app takes its org credentials from a coniguration JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yaml for this that worked for me is:

```
# Add whitelist to System Administrator profile to allow login without security token
- sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app

# Grab credentials
- sfdx force:user:password:generate --json
- CREDENTIALS=$(sfdx force:org:display --verbose --json)
- echo ${CREDENTIALS}

# Token substitute to make a usable config file
- DIR=${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/test-data/files-using-csv
- URL=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.result.instanceUrl')
- UN=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.result.username')
- PW=$(echo ${CREDENTIALS} | jq -r '.result.password')
- cat ${DIR}/config-template.json | sed 's|DIR|'${DIR}'|g;s|URL|'${URL}'|g;s|UN|'${UN}'|g;s|PW|'${PW}'|g' > ${DIR}/config-generated.json
```

where the `config-template.json` has simple upper-case text place-keepers that are substituted by `sed` such as `URL` in the JSON fragment `"instanceUrl": "URL"`.